# Why do anchor points vary in different resoliutions?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm currently trying to place text in the four corners of the screen but the thing I came across was that in some screen resolutions(e.g. 1080*1920) the anchor points aren't right in the corner. the x values for some reason are the same, but the y changes, and is not close to the corner of the screen. Here is an example of me placing some text in the top right corner:

```
local myText = display.newText( "RIGHT", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 16 )
      myText:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )
      myText.anchorX = 1
      myText.anchorY = 0
      myText.x = display.contentWidth
      myText.y = 0
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work for all screen resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you:

```
-- Top
myText.y = display.screenOriginY;

-- Bottom
myText.y = display.contentHeight - display.screenOriginY;

-- Right
myText.x = display.contentWidth - display.screenOriginX;

-- Left
myText.x = display.screenOriginX;
```

Comment: what if I wnat to place it in the bottom? How would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Tha anchor points of display objects don't change.

The coordinate system of screen change depends on scaling mode. So top-left point not always will be `(0, 0)`. For example in `letterbox` mode top-left point would be `(display.screenOriginX, display.screenOriginY)`.

From Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html#contentscaling)

```
"letterbox" — scales the content area to fill the screen while preserving the same aspect ratio. The entire content area will reside on the screen, but this might result in "black bars" on devices with aspect ratios that differ from your content aspect ratio. Note, however, that you can still utilize this "blank" area and fill it with visual elements by positioning them or extending them outside the content area bounds. Essentially, "letterbox" is an ideal scale mode if you want to ensure that everything in your content area appears within the screen bounds on all devices.

"zoomEven" — scales the content area to fill the screen while preserving the same aspect ratio. Some content may "bleed" off the screen edges on devices with aspect ratios that differ from your content aspect ratio. Basically, "zoomEven" is a good option to ensure that the entire screen is filled by the content area on all devices (and content clipping near the outer edges is acceptable).
```

- Letterbox

[image]

- zoomEven

[image]

Read more about [Content Scaling](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html#contentscaling).